# mdx with aggregate last periods not working

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am using Analysis Services on SQL server 2014, enterprise edition.

I am trying to create a new member for Timeframe dimension that aggregates last 3 months values. The following mdx code gets compiled without errors, but when I browse it with a measure, it still shows me the month level numbers, instead of last three month sum. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Timeframe].[Timeframe].[ROLLING 3 MONTH]
 AS IIF([Accounting Date].[Accounting Date].CurrentMember.Level.Name="Month", AGGREGATE(LASTPERIODS(3),[Timeframe].[Timeframe].&[1]), NULL), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Timeframe].[Timeframe].[ROLLING 3 MONTH]
 AS 
 IIF(
   [Accounting Date].[Accounting Date].CurrentMember.Level.Name="Month", 
   AGGREGATE(
    LASTPERIODS(3, [Accounting Date].[Accounting Date].CurrentMember),
    [Timeframe].[Timeframe].&[1]
   ), 
 NULL), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Specifying the member in the `LASTPERIODS` function is hopefully what you were missing. SSAS was probably assuming some other Date hierarchy or you don't have any hierarchies and dimensions properly marked. That's ok. Just specify the member and then it should work.

By the way, for performance reasons I would prefer to see a `SCOPE` statement instead of checking the level's name. What you have should work but if you hit performance issues research `SCOPE` statements or create a new thread asking to optimize that MDX.

I assume you are using Excel 2010 or higher. If not [watch out](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2010/02/18/subselects-and-calculated-members-in-r2/)!